# numpy or pandas groupby way to replace 2 for loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, numpy-ndarray

I have a following Problem there is list of main classes:

```
list_main_classes = [3,4]
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'label_col':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4], 
    'second_classes_column':[
        "class1", 
        "class2", 
        "class1", 
        "class2", 
        "class3", 
        "class3", 
        "class3", 
        "class4", 
        "class2"
    ]})
```

that has a column `"second_classes_column"`
What I am basically trying to do is remove some Elements from the list `"list_main_classes"` that satisfy certain conditions. What conditions?

1. second class columns cant be named `"certain_name"`
2. `"second_classes_column"` Elements must not appear outside of the Group created by `'label_col'`. Meaning that for a Group created by element 4 of the 'label_col'
   there must not be an element in  the `"second_classes_column"` that appears in some other group. In our case this is not satisfied by element `"class2"` since it appeared already before (rows 2 and 4). Hence we will remove the 4, but retain 3 from the list_main_classes since it satisfies everything,

**Question** is there a faster way to do this, with Pandas groupby, numpy, already done with 2 for loops ?

Comment: I'm finding it quite hard to follow what your end results should be. Are you able to provide a simple ```DataFrame``` with some example data? My initial idea would be to create a number of boolean masks, but I'm unsure if this will work as I don't know what you're trying to filter

Comment: Sure, let me know if I can Elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform a merge on the data and then a filter on the resulting dataframe.

Also if `"second_classes_column"` has more than one unique `"label_col"` assigned to it then it is invalid so you can pre-count the number of label_cols associated with each `"second_classes_column"`.

```
# setup some useful variables
main_classes = pd.DataFrame({"main_classes": list_main_classes})
count_unique_classes = data.groupby("second_classes_column")["label_col"].nunique().to_dict()

def your_logic(x):
    second_id = x["second_classes_column"]
    label_col = x["label_col"]
    
    case1 = second_id != "certain_class"
    case2 = count_unique_classes[second_id] > 1
    
    return case1 and case2

# merge the two data frames
joint_df = pd.merge(data, main_classes, left_on="label_col", right_on="main_classes")

# now you can easily do the filter and perform your logic
to_drop = joint_df.apply(your_logic, axis=1)
list_main_indexes_to_drop = joint_df[to_drop].main_classes
```

So the result:

```
>>> list_main_indexes_to_drop.values
... array([4])
```

Your final list can be obtained using either a `filter`, set operations or `np.setdiff1d`

```
>>> list(set(list_main_classes) - set(list_main_indexes_to_drop))
... [3]
```

or

```
>>> np.setdiff1d(list_main_classes, list_main_indexes_to_drop)
... array([3])
```

---

**Update**. You might not like the `your_logic` and `apply` so you can do it with vectorised boolean operations like so:

```
# setup some useful variables
main_classes = pd.DataFrame({"main_classes": list_main_classes})
count_unique_classes = data.groupby("second_classes_column")["label_col"].nunique().ge(2)
invalid_classes = set(count_unique_classes[count_unique_classes].index)

# merge the two data frames
joint_df = pd.merge(data, main_classes, left_on="label_col", right_on="main_classes")

# your logic
joint_df = joint_df[
    (joint_df.second_classes_column != "certain_class") & 
    (joint_df.second_classes_column.isin(invalid_classes)) 
]

# now you can easily do the filter and perform your logic
list_main_indexes_to_drop = joint_df.main_classes
list_main_indexes_to_drop.values
```